# opencart 1.5.1.3 encrypt() paypal pro iframe

Tags: paypal, opencart

I'm using Opencart 1.5.1 and trying to implement pay pal pro through iframe. I got a module but it doesn't work. In logs I found:

Fatal error: Call to a member function encrypt() on a non-object in .../controller/payment/pp_standard.php on line

When I try to add

```
    $registry->set('encryption', new Encryption($config->get('config_encryption')));
```

to index.php I got blank homepage and the checkout stops at the moment of choosing payment method (it's not visible). Any ideas how to reslove thios without upgrading OC ( got many changes to template files which fails to work after upgrade).

Kind regards,
Arek

Answer (score -1):

also set your error reporting to on so you can see errors and not just blank pages.